# Could automatically redirecting all HTTP traffic to HTTPS inadvertently encourage a man-in-the-middle attack vector?

Tags: security, https

If your web server implements HTTPs, it's common practice to 301 redirect all `http://*` URLs to their `https://` equivalents.

However, it occurs to me that this means that the client's original HTTP request (and any data contained in it) remains fully unencrypted, and only the response is encrypted. Does automatically "upgrading" all insecure requests on the server end effectively encourage clients to continue sending data to insecure HTTP endpoints, more or less [downgrade attacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downgrade_attack) myself?

I realize I can't *stop* a client from insecurely sending any data to *any* endpoint, but does the practice of automatically redirecting HTTP to HTTPS "condone" the client doing so? Would it be better practice to instead outright reject all HTTP traffic that could contain sensitive data and make it the *browser's* responsibility to attempt or recommend the upgrade to HTTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a known issue, and [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) (HSTS)—released in 2012—aims to solve it. It is an HTTP [header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-6.1) field which takes the form:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=<seconds> [; includeSubDomains]
```

HSTS informs the browser via that **all** connections to a given domain  **must** be "upgraded" to `https, even if they were specified as non-secure` http`:

> The UA MUST replace the URI scheme with "https"

This applies to all future connections to the domain (including following links), for the duration of the `max-age` specified in the header.

However this *does* leave open a potential vulnerability on the user's *first* visit to a domain with HSTS (if the header were stripped by an attacker). Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge attempt to limit this problem by including a "pre-loaded" list of HSTS sites.

So this preloaded list has all popular websites, All you may see in [this chromium link](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json), this list is humongous(10M), thereby solving aforementioned problem to a certain extent.